# Change Source parameter in URL without reloading page

Tags: 2013, javascript

I need **NewForm.aspx** page redirects to custom page on item added to list. I've done this by changing **Source** parameter in URL after **NewForm.aspx** has been loaded. But it makes the page to load twice.
Is there a way to change Source without page reload?

Comment: Why not change the Source in the NewForm link itself? Is there a reason why you are changing the Source parameter after NewForm.aspx has been loaded?

Comment: I try keep all customization in one place. In this way user could open NewForm in many ways including direct link but still get redirected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is **No**. After the page has been loaded and sent to the browser, there is no way to change the query string without reloading the page. Browsers only allow the part of the URL after "#" to be changed:
http://authority/path?que=ry&str=ing#anchor

You can either move the dynamic code earler (modify the link to the new form) or later (set the source parameter to target a custom page - let the custom page have dynamic code that redirects dynamically based on the system state). Can you tell us more about the requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a chance to use any kind of window preload function so this reloads looks more transparent?

Comment: If you do it server side during the initial page load, you can do a HTTP redirect. That will make the browser redirect before showing anything.

Comment: I've got the idea. Then there's no way to implement conditional rederecting, e.g. different URLs for Save and Cancel buttons? I don't use server side coding on this project, only javascript client side

Comment: Well, you could for example redirect to a page, e.g. "RedirectAfterEdit.aspx?ItemID=X&TimeStamp=Y" which checks whether the item was recently updated or not (last modified > timestamp), then redirects to different pages accordingly.